# Solr: change managed schema to schema and add new field in WINDOWS when using DIH

Tags: solr, schema, dih

I am trying to learn and create SOLR search engine for text search.

My initial step is to load a table of content from SQL to Solr. I have imported data using data import handler but Solr loaded only id field. Later I realised that the **managed schema does not work with DIH**. So I am currently switching form managed schema to classic schema.

One of the step that Solr learning material asks me to do is add new field through schema API and it has given below commands for UNIX. I am not sure its equivalent windows command. Since POST command cannot be used in windows.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field":{
     "name":"sell-by",
     "type":"tdate",
     "stored":true 
  }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/schema
```

Below is the command I used which failed,

```
curl -X  java -jar example\exampledocs\post.jar  -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field":{
    "name":"FIN", 
    "type":"int", 
      "stored":true 
  }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/#/firstcore/schema
```

Your advice or help would be much appreciated. I am stuck here for long time. I could not find how to add fields in windows. Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Did you get answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problem with your request parameter.

- First of all type `integer` not available by default if you are implemented it then it is fine.
- You have not specified request HTTP method so it takes as `GET` while it require `POST`. I think you removed it after try requesting it by `POST` but it may end-up with `Method Not Supported`.
- Above problem `Method Not Supported` is not because of `POST` method, it is because your URL was wrong, It should be `http://localhost:8983/solr/firstcore/schema`.

These are the problem which I find from your provided data and here is my example of adding field.

And Yes I am using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) as a rest client

[image: Step to Use Postman to add new field in solr]

After success operation you will see you schema file of you collection will updated in Files menu on SOLR WebApp:

To check that:

- Go to the WebApp
- Select Collection
- Click on Files
- Go to your chema file.
- Find your added field.

[image: SOLR WebApp menu]

Comment: Accepted it. This is my first post in Stackoverflow. Once again thank you for your response.

Comment: Most welcome to the one of the world's largest community. :)